# Print random price tag from a list of arrays

Tags: java

Here is an example of what I am working with:

- car color: red, yellow, white, black and gold
- car height: small, medium and large
- car type: a four-door, two-door

I would like to have java randomly (import) or pick out one of the car array lists and print it out.

I also want the prices for example red is 2.00, yellow is 4.00 printed based upon what the random is printed with the total of the height, color, and type randomly selected. I will need to select a total of 2 per category.

I am not sure where to start besides declaring the variables.

(Updated) - To have the question clearer.

I would like to clarify a bit better. 
So the example goes like this; 
I am trying to use Arraylist to generate an amount of a total of 25 Cars. These cars have different properties of the category, from the random import. Based on the properties, I am having difficulty how to start the process of assigning dollar signs to them. Like for an example; one result would be like this: Car 1: Red (2.00), Yellow (4.00), Height is small (0.50) + Height is medium (0.50), car type will be two-door (2.00) and Car type will be four-door (2.00). So the total would be the sum of all the numbers added up.

The other question is, how can I use random import to generate these items. The other question is, how can I assign the dollar signs to these items? 
(if I had to use Arraylist, how can I do this in that approach) ?

Comment: You need to post your attempt at solving this.  Only then, folks may help.

Comment: What's the specific issue, e.g., where are you stuck? Generating random numbers? Associating colors and prices? Or...?

Comment: Put all the cars in a `List`. Shuffle the `List` ([`Collections.shuffle(List<?>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-)). Iterate the shuffled list, displaying cars as you wished.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, I am stuck at the part where how I can assign dollar values to the car types. I also suck at the part of how I can use the random class to generate the list of items and adding up the total cost of the cars.

Comment: In general you'd have classes to represent the various options. Each option would have relevant data (e.g., colors would have the name of the color and the associated price). A car would have properties for each of the options. Creating a random car would consist of choosing the appropriate random options. The car's price would be a sum of those options' prices.

Comment: @firedot1 check my answer and search. this way you will learn better. if my answer was helpful to you please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark.

Comment: Maybe you should present the classes you use, and be more specific about what you call a "random import"

Answer (score 0):

One way of thinking about it is that you generate a random int between 0 and the array length and get the item at the index of that random number.

You should have a car object that includes all the properties. and your array should contain car objects.

You can have one method that calculates the price for a given object.

These hints should be enough. You can search along these lines.